# React-Admin JWT token in header

Tags: reactjs, jwt, authorization, token, react-admin

I'm testing React-Admin https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin 
and the restful API https://github.com/hagopj13/node-express-mongoose-boilerplate

I want to list the users in database but i get the error:

```
GET http://localhost:4000/v1/users?filter=%7B%7D&range=%5B0%2C24%5D&sort=%5B%22createdAt%22%2C%22desc%22%5D 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Here the Dataprovider:

```
import { fetchUtils } from "react-admin";
import { stringify } from "query-string";

const apiUrl = "http://localhost:4000/v1";
const httpClient = fetchUtils.fetchJson;

export default {
  getList: (resource, params) => {
    console.log(params.pagination);
    console.log(params.sort);
    const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
    const { field, order } = params.sort;
    const query = {
      sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
      range: JSON.stringify([(page - 1) * perPage, page * perPage - 1]),
      filter: JSON.stringify(params.filter)
    };
    const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;

    return httpClient(url).then(({ headers, json }) => ({
      data: json,
      total: parseInt(
        headers
          .get("content-range")
          .split("/")
          .pop(),
        10
      )
    }));
  },

  getOne: (resource, params) =>
    httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`).then(({ json }) => ({
      data: json
    })),

  getMany: (resource, params) => {
    const query = {
      filter: JSON.stringify({ id: params.ids })
    };
    const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
    return httpClient(url).then(({ json }) => ({ data: json }));
  },

  getManyReference: (resource, params) => {
    const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
    const { field, order } = params.sort;
    const query = {
      sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
      range: JSON.stringify([(page - 1) * perPage, page * perPage - 1]),
      filter: JSON.stringify({
        ...params.filter,
        [params.target]: params.id
      })
    };
    const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;

    return httpClient(url).then(({ headers, json }) => ({
      data: json,
      total: parseInt(
        headers
          .get("content-range")
          .split("/")
          .pop(),
        10
      )
    }));
  },

  update: (resource, params) =>
    httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: JSON.stringify(params.data)
    }).then(({ json }) => ({ data: json })),

  updateMany: (resource, params) => {
    const query = {
      filter: JSON.stringify({ id: params.ids })
    };
    return httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: JSON.stringify(params.data)
    }).then(({ json }) => ({ data: json }));
  },

  create: (resource, params) =>
    httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(params.data)
    }).then(({ json }) => ({
      data: { ...params.data, id: json.id }
    })),

  delete: (resource, params) =>
    httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`, {
      method: "DELETE"
    }).then(({ json }) => ({ data: json })),

  deleteMany: (resource, params) => {
    const query = {
      filter: JSON.stringify({ id: params.ids })
    };
    return httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
      body: JSON.stringify(params.data)
    }).then(({ json }) => ({ data: json }));
  }
};
```

For the getList, how to add the token in the header for authorization?

**Update:**

dataProvider.js

```
getList: (resource, params) => {
    /*
    console.log(params.pagination);
    console.log(params.sort);
    const {
      page,
      perPage
    } = params.pagination;
    const {
      field,
      order
    } = params.sort;
    */
    const query = {
      /*
      sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
      range: JSON.stringify([(page - 1) * perPage, page * perPage - 1]),
      filter: JSON.stringify(params.filter)
      */
    };
    const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${stringify(query)}`;
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    return httpClient(url).then(({
        headers: {
          "authorization": token
        }
      }, json
    }) => ({
      data: json,
      total: parseInt(
        headers
        .get("content-range")
        .split("/")
        .pop(),
        10
      )
    }));
  },
```

But i get this error:

```
./src/middlewares/dataProvider.js
  Line 35:5:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  33 |         }
  34 |       }, json
> 35 |     }) => ({
     |     ^
  36 |       data: json,
  37 |       total: parseInt(
  38 |         headers
```

Thanks & Regards

Ludo

Comment: You have the wrong bracket, replace } with )

Comment: If i replace with ) i have this error:    `./src/middlewares/dataProvider.js
  Line 27:6:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

  25 |       }
  26 |     }, json
> 27 |   )) => ({
     |      ^
  28 |     data: json,
  29 |     total: parseInt(
  30 |       headers`

Comment: Try to remove the bracket } completely, it is unnecessary!

Comment: I removed the unnecessary } and i get a different error: `Failed to compile
./src/middlewares/dataProvider.js
  Line 24:11:  'headers' is not defined  no-undef
`

Comment: In my opinion this is generally the wrong decision, try to see here:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#adding-custom-headers

Comment: How can i use the fetchJson in my dataProvider? I copied the token and i tried `const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
  options.user = {
    authenticated: true,
    token:
      "eyJh..."
  };
  return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
};` but i still get error 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: Look at your network request in the browser debugger and check whether its format matches the required one: "Include the JWT in requests": http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt/

Comment: I have 2 requests for login... one is empty and the other with this format `{user: {id: "5e429d562910776587c567a2", email: "admin@test.com", firstname: "Ad", lastname: "Min",…},…}
tokens: {access: {,…}, refresh: {,…}}
access: {,…}
expires: "2020-03-02T06:35:52.547Z"
token: "eyJhbGciOi..."
refresh: {,…}
expires: "2020-04-01T06:05:52.556Z"
token: "eyJhbGciOi..."
user: {id: "5e429d562910776587c567a2", email: "admin@test.com", firstname: "Ad", lastname: "Min",…}
createdAt: "2020-02-11T12:25:58.760Z"
email: "admin@test.com"
firstname: "Ad"
id: "5e429d5629107`...

Comment: No this is not the case, you need to look at the HTTP request headers.

Comment: In Request Headers 
`Provisional headers are shown
accept: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36`

Comment: There are no authorization headers here, see what they should be here:
"Include the JWT in requests": passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't really understand what to do.

Comment: @MaxAlex Now i have this in the Request Headers: `Provisional headers are shown accept: application/json authorization: [object Object] Origin: http://localhost:3000 Referer: http://localhost:3000/ User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1` And always get an error: 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: Hi, I think the content of this header should be pre-serialized:
authorization: [object Object]

Comment: Hi @MaxAlex, thanks for your time, I modified some codes in dataProvider.s and authProvider.js, And now in the Request Headers: `Provisional headers are shown
accept: application/json
access-control-expose-headers: X-Total-Count
authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR59...
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0...` But i already get the Status Code: 401 Unauthorized :(

Comment: Hello Ludo, try to see what error occurs on the server side, perhaps there is a more detailed description of the authorization error.

Comment: Ok, on the server side: `error: ::1 - GET /api/v1/users?sortBy=createdAt 401 - 9.702 ms - message: Please authenticate` So i think the error come from the auth.js?: https://github.com/hagopj13/node-express-mongoose-boilerplate/blob/master/src/middlewares/auth.js And a console log show requieredRights= getUsers (as expected) but info= "Error: No auth token" and User= false. I don't really understand this code.

Comment: In the description, the authorization header looks like this: "Authorization: JWT YOUR_JSON_WEB_TOKEN_STRING"

Comment: I tried with JWT and jwt it's doesn't work, i also tried with Bearer it's seems to work, with status code 200 OK, and the users list in reponse. But sometimes it's doesn't work because the token is null only in the header...

Comment: Here the last code: `const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
console.log("Token: " + token);

const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
  if (!options.headers) {
    options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: "application/json" });
  }

  options.headers.set("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Total-Count");
  options.headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);

  return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
}` It's really weird for me...

Comment: Sometime i have an error: `TokenExpiredError: jwt expired`, So i login again and i get a new token, but the same jwt expired error again and again... But if i restart the react-admin, or compile the code, then it's work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change your httpClient in the DataProvider, so every method will use the correct credentials.

Change this:

```
const httpClient = fetchUtils.fetchJson;
```

To this:

```
const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });
    }
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
}
```

Source: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authentication.html

Answer (score 2):

Add a const `const token = localStorage.getItem('token');` and use it in the following way

```js
getList: (resource, params) => {
  console.log(params.pagination);
  console.log(params.sort);
  const {
    page,
    perPage
  } = params.pagination;
  const {
    field,
    order
  } = params.sort;
  const query = {
    sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
    range: JSON.stringify([(page - 1) * perPage, page * perPage - 1]),
    filter: JSON.stringify(params.filter)
  };
  const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  return httpClient(url).then(({
      headers: {
        "authorization": token
      }
    }, json
  }) => ({
    data: json,
    total: parseInt(
      headers
      .get("content-range")
      .split("/")
      .pop(),
      10
    )
  }));
},
```

You can do same for other requests too.

Comment: Thanks you, i have an error ` Failed to compile.

./src/middlewares/dataProvider.js
  Line 31:5:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  29 |         }
  30 |       }, json
> 31 |     }) => ({
     |     ^
  32 |       data: json,
  33 |       total: parseInt(
  34 |         headers `